# How to get data from a device using ethernet connection with arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a question,
I know how to flush the result of a device(using PIN mode) / control a device with help of an Ethernet shield of arduino.

Now, the thing I want is I need to read a device which communicates only via Ethernet. so i have now connected the device with a router and I have the IP address of the device. I need to read the data from the device using arduino + Ethernet shield.

In fine: How to read data from a device connected to a arduino + Ethernet Sheild via lan cable and flash the result in web server or serial portal. Doesn't matter.

Please suggest a solution or help me with code.

regards,
J

Comment: What device? A web server? An IP Camera? A NAS? The question is what protocol you need to use: HTTP, FTP, TELNET, SMB, .... until then, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: The device is called "SCS EM Aware" - it sense  the electric field. The protocol can be HTTP.

Comment: Please, post a link to the exact device your are using.

Comment: http://staticcontrol.descoindustries.com/SCSCatalog/Monitors/ESD-Event-Monitors/EM-Aware-Monitor/770063/#.WnxIJKinGUk

Comment: That device communicates with their own custom server software (running in Windows) using their own custom protocol. You would need to spend a long time decoding their protocol using network sniffing software. Not a task for a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are out of luck: The device talks SMP (Static Managment Program), which is a close-source product of the same vendor.

The protocol used by SMP is not documented. The only way to access it is via the vendor own Windows software management.

Decoding the protocol is out of question.